# Operator that waits for new value in certain amount of time

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I'm looking for `observable` operator that after emitting value will wait for 500ms. 
If new value is emitted in that time it takes the new value and forget last. 
If no new value is emitted it passes this value further.

I tried:
`delay` - it only delays *every* value
`debounceTime` - it creates gaps between values and emits every one.

Comment: You can take a look at `auditTime`

Comment: `auditTime` sounds like what you need but it depends on whether you want to postpone the delay after each value from the source Observable. It think when `auditTime` receives a value it'll emit after `500ms` and won't create new timers for subsequent emissions from source.

Comment: You: "_it creates gaps between values and emits every one."_  Documentation: _"may drop some values"_ How did you come to your conclusion?

Comment: @abetteroliver You're right. Problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try throttleTime(500) and last() operators.
For example,

```
interval(100)
.pipe(
  take(10),
  throttleTime(500),
  last(),
)
.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('x', x),
  error: error => console.log('error', error),
  complete: () => console.log('complete'),
});
```

As a result, you get 6 -> complete.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `debounceTime`

> debounceTime(dueTime: number, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable
>
> Discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between
>   output

```
                 -1---2-3-4----5-6|
debounceTime(--) ----1-------4---6|
```